Which Shapely predicate should be used to distinquish between these LinearRings
In my project there are two use-cases. The red and blue shapes are not overlapping in the first case, but they do in the second.

case #1

case #2
In my test code I tried various predicates from Shapely but could not find anyway to tell them apart.
from shapely import LinearRing

# first use-case
blue_sq = LinearRing([(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1)])
red_one = LinearRing([(0, 0), (0, 3), (3, 3), (3, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (0, 0)])

print(blue_sq.overlaps(red_one))
print(blue_sq.intersects(red_one))
print(blue_sq.crosses(red_one))
print(blue_sq.contains(red_one))
print(blue_sq.touches(red_one))
print(blue_sq.within(red_one))

# second use-case
blue_ln = LinearRing([(2, 1), (2, 2), (7, 2), (7, 1), (2, 1)])
red_two = LinearRing([(1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 0), (1, 0)])

print(blue_ln.overlaps(red_two))
print(blue_ln.intersects(red_two))
print(blue_ln.crosses(red_two))
print(blue_ln.contains(red_two))
print(blue_ln.touches(red_two))
print(blue_ln.within(red_two))

The results are summarised in the table below.



Shapely predicate
case 1
case 2




overlaps
True
True


intersects
True
True


crosses
False
False


contains
False
False


touches
False
False


within
False
False



Both cases appear to intersect and overlap, but neither case crosses, contains, touches or lies within the other. I feel sure that I am missing something obvious :-)

To support the answer of Pieter look at LinearRing.touches returns False?

A LinearRing is still just a line... so considering that both cases are indeed very similar and there are no differences in the results of the predicates.
A difference appears when you consider the coordinates as the outer border of a surface. To use the lines like that you need to use them to create Polygons in shapely. If you do that, you get the expected different results.
Code sample:
from shapely import Polygon

# first use-case
blue_sq = Polygon([(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1)])
red_one = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 3), (3, 3), (3, 2), (1, 2), (1, 0), (0, 0)])

print(f"{blue_sq.overlaps(red_one)=}")
print(f"{blue_sq.intersects(red_one)=}")
print(f"{blue_sq.crosses(red_one)=}")
print(f"{blue_sq.contains(red_one)=}")
print(f"{blue_sq.touches(red_one)=}")
print(f"{blue_sq.within(red_one)=}")

# second use-case
blue_ln = Polygon([(2, 1), (2, 2), (7, 2), (7, 1), (2, 1)])
red_two = Polygon([(1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 0), (1, 0)])

print(f"{blue_ln.overlaps(red_two)=}")
print(f"{blue_ln.intersects(red_two)=}")
print(f"{blue_ln.crosses(red_two)=}")
print(f"{blue_ln.contains(red_two)=}")
print(f"{blue_ln.touches(red_two)=}")
print(f"{blue_ln.within(red_two)=}")

Output:
blue_sq.overlaps(red_one)=False
blue_sq.intersects(red_one)=True
blue_sq.crosses(red_one)=False
blue_sq.contains(red_one)=False
blue_sq.touches(red_one)=True
blue_sq.within(red_one)=False
blue_ln.overlaps(red_two)=True
blue_ln.intersects(red_two)=True
blue_ln.crosses(red_two)=False
blue_ln.contains(red_two)=False
blue_ln.touches(red_two)=False
blue_ln.within(red_two)=False 


Since posting the question, I was starting to convert the LinearRings into lines because the crosses predicate then gave the desired result. Converting to Polygons is a much cleaner way of detecting the difference. Thanks!
